# Parsing Character Sets without Converting to UTF-8

Tags: regex, parsing, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

I'm working on parsing/tokenizing a set of languages that compile to CSS and I'm stuck as to how I should handle non-ASCII inputs. Obviously many people have dealt with this before.

*As a general rule of thumb*, I keep reading "convert to UTF-8, process, and convert back to whatever encoding you had as input." I would tend to agree with that approach...

*But I keep thinking*, all the punctuation and numbers I'm going to be working with directly are ASCII (with code points below 127) ant the other character strings are all going to be stuffed in a hash table (i.e. the program *shouldn't* care how many bytes you need to express any given character).

**Here come the questions:**

- Is there any formal character set that would **conflict** with the ASCII definitions for the code points I'm interested in (all below 127)?
- Can you see any blatant error in setting big ole' character ranges in order to match all the characters I'm not going to deal with directly and skipping the whole wide character UTF-8 encode decode fiasco?

For example:

```
//A-Z, a-z and all the non-ASCII stuff
character = (0x41..0x5A) || (0x61..0x7A) || (0x80..0xFF)

//match 1 or more
identifier = character+
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: You're not saying what it is you plan to do to this text but I wouldn't be so worried about UTF-8. It should be easy enough to interpret as you go and just copy what you don't want to deal with in special ways.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. As long as I spit it out back in the same order and encoding, I believe.

Comment: There *are* many encoding schemes which are *not* ASCII compatible, from non-ASCII single-byte encodings to UTF-16, Big5 and co. The question is, are you realistically going to encounter those?

Comment: True, I suppose UTF-8 being the "defacto standard" and being ASCII compatible I could get a decent coverage from focusing on the ascii symbols which are relevant to my grammar and letting the user deal with whether 0xCF 0x80 (pi) is one byte or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to go with encoding oblivious (like PHP), then you cannot support input encodings like UTF-16 I.E. the encoding must be ASCII compatible *bitwise*. Not to be confused with ASCII compatibility in character sets.

Encoding oblivious will work well for you since data is just passing through. If you needed to deal with character content in any other way - that would require decoding each time and so you might as well
decode it once at the beginning.

Do not encode (and thus require decoding, declarations, detections and other complexity) the content in UTF-8, just pass it through. If input was UTF-8, output will be UTF-8. If input was Windows-1252, output will be Windows-1252. Least surprise...

Answer (score 0):

[EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC). But you shouldn't need to worry about that.

Generally, though, I'd say the sanest approach would be to accept whatever encoding as input and just spit out UTF-8.